# Better way to write a pattern synonym

Tags: haskell

In the course of my travels, I have written this pattern synonym:

```
pattern ConsK :: a -> D k (StreamK k a) -> StreamK k a
pattern ConsK x xs <- StreamK (Cons x ((UnsafeD . StreamK) -> xs)) where
    ConsK x (UnsafeD (StreamK xs)) = StreamK (Cons x xs)
```

The last line captures the intent of this pattern synonym: the virtual constructor `ConsK` both wraps (with `StreamK`) and unwraps (`xs`) its arguments. When I pattern match on this constructor, I simply want the wrapping operations to unwrap, and the unwrapping operations to wrap.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, I have to write an extremely ugly, `ViewPatterns`ed pattern synonym. Is there any way to write this better?

Comment: Good question, though it could use a bit more context.

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do it. In order to perform any kind of computation in a pattern you need to use a view pattern.

Comment: The insult to injury is UnsafeD and StreamK are newtypes. No computation!

Comment: Well, I posted a GHC bug https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12203#ticket