# No-fun/puzzlement with pattern synonyms as functions

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

With `PatternSynonyms` ([explicitly bidirectional form](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#syntax-and-scoping-of-pattern-synonyms)), the pattern-to-expr equations in effect form a function but spelled upper-case (providing you end up with an fully saturated data constr of the correct type). Then consider (at GHC 8.10.2)

```
{-# LANGUAGE  PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns  #-}

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat                deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

--  Pattern Synonyms as functions?

pattern Pred :: Nat -> Nat
pattern Pred n <- {- what goes here? -}           where
  Pred (Succ n) = n
pattern One           = Succ Zero

zero = Pred One                      -- shows as Zero OK
```

So what do I put for the `pattern Pred n <- ???` value-to-pattern top line? Or can I just not use `Pred n` in a pattern match? What seems to work (but I don't understand why) is a view pattern

```
pattern Pred n <-  (Succ -> n)          where ...   -- seems to work, but why?

isZero (Pred One) = True
isZero _          = False

-- isZero (Pred One) ===> True ; isZero Zero ===> True
-- isZero (Succ One) ===> False; isZero One  ===> False
```

It looks sweet to use `Pred` as a pseudo-constructor/pattern here, because it's an injective function.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890385/better-way-to-write-a-pattern-synonym, and see the Trac issue link from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this usage of your pattern synonym:

```
succ' :: Nat -> Nat
succ' (Pred n) = n
```

where the intent is, of course, to return the successor of the argument.

In this case it is clear that when the argument is, say, `k`, then variable `n` must be bound to `Succ k`. Given this intuition, we need to find a pattern that does exactly that, a pattern that could be used here instead of `Pred n`:

```
succ' :: Nat -> Nat
succ' ({- bind n to Succ k -}) = n
```

It turns out that your view pattern does exactly that. This would work just fine:

```
succ' :: Nat -> Nat
succ' (Succ -> n) = n
```

Consequently, we have to define

```
pattern Pred n <- (Succ -> n)
```

In my own (limited) experience, this is fairly idiomatic. When you have a bidirectional pattern synonym, you will often use a view pattern as done above.

Comment: Aha! Would there be a way to do this without View Patterns? (Asking because I find them not intuitive, what with that invisible argument.)

Comment: @AntC I don't think it's possible without.